# C# SQL UPDATE SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I am having silly trouble with an `UPDATE` statement. I am trying to change password in a user table with `UPDATE`, and I keep getting "syntax error". Can't find the reason...

In my table, I have 6 different columns including `username` and `password`.

```
String salt = ""; // Initializing salt string variable to save the salt

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database_MT.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=********************");
con.Open(); //Opening the connection

OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE users SET password = @pass WHERE username = @user", con);

salt = CreateRandomSalt();

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", hashPassword(newPasswordTextBox.Text, salt));
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", verifiedUser);

try
{
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string newException = ex.ToString();
    ThreadExceptionForm newEx = new ThreadExceptionForm(newException);
    newEx.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: What does your schema look like? What is the *actual* error you're receiving?

Comment: what does the output of hashPassword method look like?

Comment: i get exactly this:   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password columnname and/or the users table-name might be keywords, so you'll have to escape them.
In SQL Server you use brackets to do so:

```
UPDATE [users] SET [password] = @pass WHERE username = @user
```

Comment: That works like charm!! Thanks! Didn't think about it